# In a causal diagram where the change score $\Delta Y=Y_1-Y_0$, does $Y_1$ cause $\Delta Y$ or does $\Delta Y$ cause $Y_1$?

Tags: difference-in-difference, pre-post-comparison, dag, causal-diagram

In [Shahar & Shahar (2010)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2753.2010.01540.x), the authors argue that in a typical pre/post observational study on two longitudinal outcomes $Y_0$ and $Y_1$:

- the change score $\Delta Y=Y_1-Y_0$ causes the post-period outcome $Y_1$, or
- the post-period outcome $Y_1$ causes $\Delta Y$.

Which is true?

If either statement could be true, does that invalidate using change scores (and difference-in-differences) for causal inference because the direction of the causal arrow connecting $\Delta Y$ and $Y_1$ cannot be clarified?